# How to get thick hairs

Tags: particles, hair

With the hair particles. I tried to tweak the setting to have thick hairs. Im making brush. Rendering in cycles. In the rendering i have set to thick. I want to have the V shape. Growing from below and making a V shape. I do not want to use object such as cylinder etc. With the hair settings i want to get the result.

[image]

[image]

**Not thick**

[image]

Im looking for this type of hair setting
[image]

Comment: The hairs in  your example have a constant thickness, but are placed in a V shape. Your question however seems to be about having hair that is thicker on the root and smaller on the tip.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the curve rendering setting under **Render Properties > Curves > Strip**

You can then adjust the Diameter Root and Tip values under **Particle Properties > Hair Shape** to adjust the size of the base and tip of the hair, allowing you to create a "V" shape.

Alternatively, you can also explore the use of [geometry and hair nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/hair/write/set_hair_curve_profile.html) if you need more control than this allows.

Comment: no it did not work

Comment: I download!
you using cycles and you see in your viewport mode! go to render view https://prnt.sc/u89snp

Comment: As per the brush V shape and thick i want to have that setting. The link image hairs not so thick as compare to my reference image

Comment: Change the thickness with "Diameter Scale". You must be in rendered or material preview mode to see the changes.