# Hair diameter remains infinitesimal even if I change values

Tags: particles, hair

Even if I set very high root values, the hair diameter in the rendering remains infinitesimal. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192792/how-to-get-thick-hairs. Hair diameter is straightforward in Cycles, while in Eevee you have to turn curves preference in Render tab from "Strand" to "Strip".